# Unable to create Google Wallet Merchant Account

Tags: google-checkout, android-pay

I am trying to create a Google Wallet Merchant Account so that I can use the Google Wallet for Digital Goods API.

Step 1 is to "Sign Up for a merchant account".

Strangely, the form is mostly, but entirely prefilled, and there is a link that says "Why can't I edit my address?" that does nothing when I click on it.

So, I fill out the form with the remaining information and hit "Complete Signup", only to get "An error occured while processing your request".  Every time.

Interestingly, if I go into Google Wallet for Business, it appears I already have a merchant account, but there still seems to be no way for me to make progress to get the Seller ID and Seller Secret needed to use the Digital Goods ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to unblock this by actually finding the Google Wallet support line here: https://support.google.com/wallet/business/contact/phone, where I was able to get someone on the phone in minutes to help me figure out the issue here.

It turns out that at some point in the past, I had created a Google Checkout account for my business (which is how the forms were prefilled and I already had a merchant account), and a pre-existing Google Checkout merchant account is incompatible with a new Google Wallet merchant account.

There are two solutions to this, according to the person I spoke with:

- Use a different Google Account that doesn't already have a Google Checkout merchant account to create your Google Wallet Merchant Account, which you can do immediately.
- They can migrate your account for you (and you'll have to contact them as I've listed above), but this takes 2-3 business days.

I hope this proves to be useful for someone else.